# Refactoring of unit-tests (Jasmine)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, refactoring, jasmine

During changing business logic we need to refactor the code and the unit-tests. In sources in Jasmine recomending to use x-blockes (such as xdescribe or xit) or function pending() to skip obsolete tests. Say me how is it right:

- use recomended methods (above)?
- remove obsolete blocks describe(it)?

What are the advantages / disadvantages of the first and second approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) These methods are identical.
I advise you to use the x-blocks, because this more clearly and more comfortably to support.

2) You should not be afraid to remove obsolete blocks of tests (it). But for saving common logic of test-suits I recommend you don't delete describe blocks in beginning of refactoing (xdescribe be useful in that case).